# Google Drive SDK and API

Tags: android, google-api, google-drive-api, google-play-services

I have an Android application using the new Google Play Services.  I am able to successfully authenticate users and get a token back.  Now that I have a token, I have a script on a sever that uses this token to perform some actions.  When I try to do a simple REST API call such as:
    GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/about

I get the error 'Access Not Configured'.  I checked my API Console and I have Drive API and Drive SDK enabled.

Is this not possible? Or am I going about this the wrong way?

Thanks

Comment: What does "a script on a server" mean? It's running on a completely different machine? Not on the android device that requested the token?

Answer (score 0):

You're probably missing a scope. Here is a full set

```
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file",
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive",
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile",
"https://docs.googleusercontent.com/",
"https://docs.google.com/feeds/",
```

Perhaps start with that to get your app working, then remove the ones you don't actually use.

Comment: The scope im using is "oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive" when authenticating with Google Play Services.  I believe that should cover me for all Drive API calls.